# How to count no. of null occurrences along with its property name from a JSON response

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
public class JsonContainer {
@JsonProperty("a")
private List<String> a = null;
@JsonProperty("b")
private String b;
//  And their corresponding getter and setter methods
}
```

Below code snippet is from a different class:

```
JsonContainer[] jc = null;
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
URL url = new URL("sample_url");
try {
  jc = objectMapper.readValue(url, JsonContainer[].class);
}
```

From the url, few of the property values are expected to have null values and this needs to be tracked (final count of null values against the property names - meaning once all of the JSON objects from the url are processed).
e.g.

```
{ "a": null, 
  "b": "newyork"
 },
{ "a": "test1", 
  "b": null
 },
```

In this case, the count of null occurrences would be `a = 1, b = 1`.
How could i achieve this?

Note: The JSON response returned is an array of objects and hence i am storing it as a Array[].

Comment: *"The url is expected to have null values"* That makes no sense. Did you mean that the **JSON** has null values, e.g. `{ "a": null, "b": [1, null, 2] }`? Edit the question and show example of the what you mean.

Comment: @Andreas, yes, you are right. Few of the property values are expected to have null values

Comment: I'll repeat myself: Edit the question and **show example** of the what you mean. Also explain/show what you mean by *"final count of null values against the property names"*.

Comment: @Andreas, i have edited my question

Comment: What is `JsonContainer`? Are the list of keys to count fixed? --- Perhaps you should use `readTree()` instead of `readValue()`, so you can process the entire JSON structure in a generic way, and result would be a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: You deserialize JSON to array of objects anyway. Why you do not want to do that after deserialization?